# How do I download Azure devops repo as a zip file using Azure automation runbook?

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, git-clone, azure-automation

I am trying to create an automation runbook to backup one of our Azure Devops repository and store it as a Zip file in the storage account. But when I run Git clone in a runbook(imported the posh-git module)I am getting the below error. Is there any way I can download the whole git repo as a Zip file using Automation Runbook?

```
git : Cloning into 'testrepo'... At line:1 char:1 
+ git clone https://FAKEehtinrtsndtsrihdintsrhdinrhtidhtsrdFAKE... 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (Cloning into 'testrepo'...:String) [], RemoteException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: That looks awfully much like a Azure DevOps Personal Access Token. Be sure to revoke it!

Comment: just a suggestion: have you thought about this the other way around? have a build that takes all of the repo files and stores it as a zip to storage? the reason im asking is that by design the PAT is 'personal', so if you  quit or forget to update YOUR token, the solution breaks. if you build it the other way around, you can use service principal. also you can have it trigger when specific things happen in the repo and not just "every day at 12"

Comment: Let's take a step even further back: What is the concern that's driving this solution? Repos by design have history of every change that's made to them and can easily be restored to a prior state. And every developer has a local copy of the repo. What is the scenario in which you need this backup?

Comment: @PhilipMeholm Yeah I did think about that, but we are specifically looking for a time-based trigger from a Runbook instead of a pipeline in DevOps. This way it won't be triggered every time there is a commit to the repos.

Comment: @DrSpring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers

Comment: @PhilipMeholm Thanks for the link, I am able to schedule the pipeline for a specific branch.

Comment: @DrSpring Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! @BhargaviAnnadevara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a DevOps pipeline to clone, archive, and copy the repository to a storage account as a Zip file and set up 10 days retention for the Zip files.
Below are the steps:

1. Create a container in the [Azure storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal).
2. Generate a new [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) in Azure DevOps with 'Read' access to 'Code'
3. Create a new [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Azure DevOps to access the Azure subscription that contains the storage account.
4. Create a YAML pipeline with the code [here](https://github.com/vasanth-janakiraman/Devops).